# inserting am html form into a codeigniter controller

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

So, I am working on this page: http://btcbidder.com/user/sell/

Inside my user.php controller, I have a sell function. The sell function looks like this:

```
public function sell()
{
        require_once(APPPATH . 'views/sessiondata.inc.php');//sets up variables from session data
        require_once(APPPATH . 'views/header.inc.php');//header
        include(APPPATH . 'views/breadcrumbs.inc.php');//top breadcrumbs

        include(APPPATH . 'views/form.html');//top breadcrumbs


        //print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
        include(APPPATH . 'views/breadcrumbs.inc.php');//bottom breadcrumbs
        require_once(APPPATH . 'views/footer.inc.php');//footer
    }
```

The HTML form which is included is available at: http://miconserve.org/test/form.html
I hosted it there for anyone curious about this.

Anyway, you can see that on the Miconserve website, the form loads as expected. 
However, when it loads in the btcbidder site, it overlaps the bottom of the page.

What could be causing this?

Comment: So why exactly are you using codeigniter if you're not using any of its functionality such as its template system? or its session system?

Comment: use the instance of View class instead of doing that everytime.

Comment: I paid a guy to start this project for me. He used codeigniter. That was in December. After 20k excuses, he still hadnt come close to finishing. Basically, I fired him, and am doing things as a solo project now. I've read alot of the documentation, but I'm still new to PHP. An added note, I am using its session system. The sessiondata.inc.php include you see above just initializes variables for the page based on the current logged in user. (it holds thier bitcoin wallet address, email address, and username, as they are primary keys for various tables)

Comment: just replace that code its a bad practice. i'll give you an example on how to do it.

Comment: I'm with @Miks here, The code epitome of antipattern for CI, using the built in functionality will make it superbly easier

Comment: Sure thing. Can I get an example, @Miks?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who had seen the way it was overlapping, it was a CSS problem.

I fixed it by removing the height line in the hard-codeed CSS pertaining to forms in the header.inc.php file, which was included right before the form itself.

Solved.